# Does the Scanner class load the entire file into memory at once?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I often use the Scanner class to read files because it is so convenient.

```
      String inputFileName;
      Scanner fileScanner;

      inputFileName = "input.txt";
      fileScanner = new Scanner (new File(inputFileName));
```

My question is, does the above statement load the entire file into memory at once? Or do subsequent calls on the fileScanner like

```
      fileScanner.nextLine();
```

read from the file (i.e. from external storage and not from memory)? I ask because I am concerned about what might happen if the file is too huge to be read into memory all at once. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is No. But it reads file by buffer - which means in chunks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you read the source code you can answer the question yourself.

It appear that the implementation of the Scanner constructor in question shows:

```
public Scanner(File source) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this((ReadableByteChannel)(new FileInputStream(source).getChannel()));
}
```

Latter this is wrapped into a Reader:

```
private static Readable makeReadable(ReadableByteChannel source, CharsetDecoder dec) {
    return Channels.newReader(source, dec, -1);
}
```

And it is read using a buffer size

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024; // change to 1024;
```

As you can see in the final constructor in the construction chain:

```
private Scanner(Readable source, Pattern pattern) {
        assert source != null : "source should not be null";
        assert pattern != null : "pattern should not be null";
        this.source = source;
        delimPattern = pattern;
        buf = CharBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
        buf.limit(0);
        matcher = delimPattern.matcher(buf);
        matcher.useTransparentBounds(true);
        matcher.useAnchoringBounds(false);
        useLocale(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));
    }
```

So, it appears scanner does not read the entire file at once.

Comment: +1 Wasn't aware it didn't read the entire file at once. Answer edited. However, it does still run into problems with larger files which a BufferedReader + FileReader does not.

Comment: @Aidanc What kind of problems?

Answer (score 2):

From reading the code, it appears to load 1 KB at a time by default. The size of the buffer can increase for long lines of text. (To the size of the longest line of text you have)

Answer (score 1):

In ACM Contest the fast read is very important. In Java we found found that use something like that is very faster...

```
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
    InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int trees = 0;
    for (String s; (s = in.readLine()) != null; trees++) {
        Integer n = map.get(s);
        if (n != null) {
            map.put(s, n + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(s, 1);
        }
    }
```

The file contains, in that case, tree names...

```
Red Alder
Ash
Aspen
Basswood
Ash
Beech
Yellow Birch
Ash
Cherry
Cottonwood
```

You can use the `StringTokenizer` for catch any part of line that your want.

We have some errors if we use `Scanner` for large files. Read 100 lines from a file with 10000 lines!

> A scanner can read text from any object which implements the Readable
>   interface. If an invocation of the underlying readable's
>   Readable.read(java.nio.CharBuffer) method throws an IOException then
>   the scanner assumes that the end of the input has been reached. The
>   most recent IOException thrown by the underlying readable can be
>   retrieved via the ioException() method.

tells in the API

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're better off going with something like [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) with a [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) for large files. A basic example can be found [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml).

Comment: @Sheriff See edalorzo's answer. It appears I'm mistaken about reading the entire file, however I've left my answer because Buffered + FileReader does handle large files better.

Comment: @Aidanc - why do you say that?  Surely it depends on whether or not you need Scanner's parsing functionality.  Sure, if the OP is **only** going to use `nextLine()`, a BufferedReader could be a bit faster.  (Note that the OP says "subsequent calls on the fileScanner **like** `fileScanner.nextLine()`" ...)

Comment: Why do you think BufferedReader is better?