# Relative Frequency Count of letters (a-z) from a text file in Java

Tags: java

My text input file has already been processed and only contains letters (a-z) and spaces.  For some reason, when I input a very large text file (about 400 000 word file,as determined via cutting and pasting into MSWord), the relative frequency count fails.  but for smaller files it works e.g total character=36.  Please can someone tell me where the code is going wrong?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SoloCount {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
String inputFile = "sampleOutput.txt";


// My array for the a-z (97-122, based on ASCII table )

try {
int[] myArray = new int[26];
BufferedReader readerObject = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
String sCurrentLine="";
sCurrentLine = readerObject.readLine();

for(int i = 0; i<sCurrentLine.length(); i++)  // for each character in the readline                    from the input file, a-z will be counted.
        {
            if (Character.isLetter(sCurrentLine.charAt(i)) == true)     // qualifies characterisa letter and not an empty space.
            {
            char singleLetter = sCurrentLine.charAt(i);
            myArray[(int)(singleLetter)-97] = myArray[(int)(singleLetter)-97] + 1;  // Assigning frequency of a character. 97-122 represents a-z (ASCII table). e.g lowercase c = 97
            }
        }
        readerObject.close();


    //Calculate the total number of characters from the input file.
    double sumOfCharacters= 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) 
    {
        sumOfCharacters += myArray[i];
    }
    System.out.println("The total number of characters in this file is: " + sumOfCharacters);

    //Calculating the realtive frequency.  Divide each occurrence for each letter (a-z) by the sumOfCharacters.
    System.out.printf("%10s%6s%n", "Letter", "%");   //column labels "Letter" and "%"
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) 
    {
        char singleLetter = (char)(i + 97);         //converting the decimal ASCII annotation to letters for a-z
        double value = myArray[i];
        System.out.printf("%8s%13f%n",singleLetter,(value/sumOfCharacters)*100);
    }

    } 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "fails"?

Comment: Your code only reads the first line of the file. Is this intentional?

Comment: it appears to give me the output of a previous run that worked. even though the input file is different and of a different text content.

Comment: my code is supposed to read all the file - That is the hope.

Comment: Well, the input file is always `sampleOutput.txt`, are you changing the contents of that file? You're also only reading the very first line.

Comment: You have one `readLine()` call. How do you suppose that reads the entire file?

Comment: i am changing the content of that input file yes.....ValeKHalfHeart mentioned that my code only reads one line of the total file...that could explain it...can someone please help me with the code to read all the lines of the file?

Comment: See [how to read all the lines of a file using java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715557/how-to-read-all-the-lines-of-a-file-using-java-code).

Comment: Thanks everyone! Sorted!!

Answer (score 1):

You are reading only one line of your file - it could be that there are only 36 characters on the line or there is a newline character after 36 characters.

You can also increase the buffer size of your BufferedReader by passing in a larger initial buffer size -

```
BufferedReader readerObject = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile), 2048);
```

For more details please see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader%28java.io.Reader,%20int%29).